# Setting default system-wide environment for Python

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

My company releases part of its product as Python scripts running on an embedded Linux-based system. For our production release, I want to set the environment variable PYTHONOPTIMIZE="1" so that all Python scripts will be run as if the "-OO" switch were specified.

However, the scripts will be running by a user who isn't logged in (for example, some are invoked via the web server and others are started via systemd) so I can't simply set PYTHONOPTIMIZE in, e.g., /etc/profiles.

One solution might be to modify the shebang in each Python script to include the "-OO" switch but this seems a little involved. Is there an obvious way to make Python execute all Python scripts using a default environment that I missed?

Comment: /etc/environment ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no (I checked, including a reboot). I believe /etc/environment is for login, too.